# Can European player sign for NBD-League team during the season?

Tags: basketball, transfer, nbdl

Can European player sign for [NBDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Development_League) team during the season?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an overseas player can join the NBA DLeague during the season.  If a player wants to go to the DLeague, he is placed in a player pool, and is able to be selected by a team via waivers.

- Once the NBA D-League season begins, players who sign NBA D-League contracts are placed into a rotating waiver pool so that teams can claim them.
- If a player from high school, college or overseas enters the NBA D-League without ever having declared for the NBA Draft, he will also join the waiver pool. That player remains NBA Draft-eligible but is not eligible to be called up to the NBA.

[Source](http://dleague.nba.com/faq/)